# What is the difference between perfrom_async and delay in Sidekiq?

Tags: actionmailer, background-process, sidekiq, asynchronous

When reading the [Sidekiq Wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki) I see the following examples:

From [Getting started](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Getting-Started):

> Send a message to be processed asynchronously:
>
> ```
> HardWorker.perform_async('bob', 5)
> ```
>
> You can also send messages by calling the delay method on a class method:
>
> ```
> User.delay.do_some_stuff(current_user.id, 20)
> ```

Also, from [Delayed extensions](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-extensions):

> Use delay to deliver your emails asynchronously. Use delay_for(interval) or delay_until(time) to deliver the email at some point in the future.
>
> UserMailer.delay.welcome_email(@user.id)
>      UserMailer.delay_for(5.days).find_more_friends_email(@user.id)
>      UserMailer.delay_until(5.days.from_now).find_more_friends_email(@user.id)

So what is actually the difference between `perfrom_async` and `delay`? In which situations would I prefer the one over the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

perform_async is Sidekiq's native API.  delay is a compatibility API with DelayedJob.  Use perform_async when possible.

Comment: Is there a different between which one automatically calls `.deliver` on the Mail object for you and which doesn't?

Comment: delay on an ActionMailer calls deliver for you.  perform_async is a generic background call, you'll need to call deliver in the perform method.

Comment: "Use perform_async when possible" @MikePerham So why does the documentation (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-extensions) imply delay is recommended for ActiveRecord and ActionMailer?